# Installing relasense D435 on raspberry 3

Tags: openssl, raspberry-pi3, realsense

i am following this guide for install the sdk of a RealSense camera D435 on raspberry 3 [Link](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation_raspbian.md)

When i put the command:

```
 cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=true -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DFORCE_LIBUVC=true
```

in the part "install RealSense SDK/librealsense", i have this error:

```
        -- Building libcurl enabled
    CMake Error at /home/pi/cmake-3.11.4/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
      Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
      system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
      OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /home/pi/cmake-3.11.4/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      /home/pi/cmake-3.11.4/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:390 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      CMake/external_libcurl.cmake:56 (find_package)
      CMake/global_config.cmake:93 (include)
      CMakeLists.txt:44 (global_set_flags)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed? If somewhere non-standard, did you `try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR `...?

Comment: How can I do via terminal?

Comment: I solved with : sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Hello, I'm working on a similar project, your objective is to have to real time streaming via  RPi4 IP? if so how do you access this flux? thanks